# An object reference is required for the non-static field error

Tags: c#

I have a long method that ends up returning a DataTable. The method opens like this:

```
    public DataTable ImportCsvData(string folderPath, string[] csvFileNames, int compIdValue)
    {
        int countDupFiles = 0;// Count number of previously imported csv files
        int countImportedFiles = 0;// Count imported files

        for (int i = 0; i < csvFileNames.Length; i++)
        {
            frmImportCsvData.importProgressBar(i);
```

This method is inside a class where I am doing all of my SQL requests but is called from another class that controls my Form. The last line of code above calls a method back in my Form class which should update my progress bar. The code for that method is:

```
public void importProgressBar(int i)
        {
            progressTableLayoutPanel.Visible = true;//display progress bar

            int percProgress = 100 * (i + 1) / csvFileNames.Length;

            while (percProgress < 100)
            {
                if (percProgress <= 99)// Required to prevent values above 100 that crash the code
                    progressBar.Value = percProgress + 1;//hack that makes the progress bar update when progress value decreases
                progressBar.Value = percProgress;
                percProgressLabel.Text = percProgress.ToString();

                progressTableLayoutPanel.Update();//Required to display all progress bar table contents
                //Thread.Sleep(200);
            }
            progressTableLayoutPanel.Visible = false;
        }
```

This gives me the error: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'BetfairDatabaseMDI.frmImportCsvData.importProgressBar(int)'. If I set the importProgressBar method to static I get a bunch of other similar errors. Could anybody advise me how to fix this please?

Comment: One way to do this is to use a background worker and then call the report progress method when you want to update your progress bar. Another way is to run ImportCsvData in another thread and create an event that fires when "i" is updated and passes the new "i" value. Then handle that event on your form and update the progress bar on the main thread.

Comment: i don't exactly know it works or not but use Delegate here Func<> through it you can return any number of values correct me if i'm wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`frmImportCsvData` is a class, so a *type*, which is an abstract thing, not a real object in memory. The error message says you need an *instance* of a type, so a concrete, existing thing, an object in memory of that given *type*.

So, essentially, you need to pass the *instance* of `frmImportCsvData` into `ImportCsvData`. For example, like this:

```
public DataTable ImportCsvData(frmImportCsvData myForm, …)
{
    myForm.importProgressBar(i);
}
```

Then to call the method ***from within `frmImportCsvData`*** you just pass in `this`, which denotes the current instance (in run-time sense) of the enclosing class:

```
dataLayer.ImportCsvData(this, …);
```

Simplest doesn't mean best or correct in respect to the particular UI framework you are using (being it WinForms, WPF, whatever). **BUT:** You definitelly have to understand the differences between a type and an instance of a type ***first***, before you run into any more complex constructs. So grab a C# book and get back to the basics, that will help you the most.

---

Note: It is a common convention to start identifiers of methods, classes and properties with an upper-case letter.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So if I have:
public DataTable ImportCsvData(frmImportCsvData myForm, string folderPath, string[] csvFileNames, int compIdValue)
How do I call the method? Currently I have:
dataLayer.ImportCsvData(folderPath, csvFileNames, compIdValue);

Comment: @SteveW Later on as you study, you'll figure out that lower layers of your software, such as the data layer, shall not have direct depedencies on higher layers, such as the UI. There are principally two ways around: a) make the data layer accept an interface, which has no such dependencies, or b) create an event in the data layer, which the UI can subscribe.